# How to fetch two elements from XML to create Triples using TDE?

Tags: xml, marklogic

WHEN I am keeping CONTEXT as `/Rule/Concepts/RuleConcepts/Concept`

I am able to get the `DispalyName(/Rule/Concepts/RuleConcepts/Concept/DiaplayName)` as Subject

But I am not able to get Name `element(/Rule/Concepts/RuleConcepts/Concept/Synonyms/Synonym/Name )` as Object.

I am getting below error

> Eval for Object='xs:string(Name)' returns an empty sequence .

But WHEN I am keeping  `<context>/Rule/Concepts/RuleConcepts/Concept//Synonyms/Synonym</context>`

then I am able to get the object element but not the Subject one.

HOW TO GET BOTH elements?

PS: TDE for triples.

Thanks,
Anuj "

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the TDE template you are using? Anonymized if you like..

Comment: Added. Now can you please help..

Comment: Please add the entire TDE template..